# GitHub Action to deploy Ansible playbook on EC2 in private subnet

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, github-actions, private-subnet

I am trying to run an Ansible playbook against an EC2 instance in a private subnet, but I am having trouble.

I tried running this workflow file:

```yaml
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: terraform ssh key
        uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.7.0
        with:
          ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.EC2_PRIVATE_KEY }}       
      - name: Run playbook
        uses: dawidd6/action-ansible-playbook@v2
        with:
          playbook: deploy.yaml
          directory: ./
          inventory: |
            [all]
            10.2.13.227
```

This is my playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  vars:
    - ansible_ssh_user: "admin"
    - ansible_ssh_common_args: >
          -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q ec2-user@13.37.97.97" -i ~/keys/fr-prod.pem \
          -o ServerAliveInterval=5 \
          -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
  tasks:
    - name: example
      debug:
        msg: Hello World from {{ inventory_hostname }}!
```

I expected this to connect to by private instance and show me this message:

```
Hello World from 10.2.13.227
```

Instead, I got this error:

```
> fatal: [10.2.13.227]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host\r\nConnection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535", "unreachable": true}
```

I think this error is caused by the SSH key being forwarded incorrectly. How can I fix this?

Comment: If the EC2 instance is in a **private** subnet, it won't be directly exposed to incoming traffic from the internet... `10.2.13.227` is a private IP address.

Comment: Thats what the shh arges where for I was trying to proxy through my bastion